# Strange macro behavior from Excel VBA after Windows upgrade

Tags: excel

I have a macro that produces a report by processing 70+ Excel files and has been working for many months and still works on another laptop I have. My main laptop was upgraded to Windows 11 about 10 days ago and while the macro worked last week, it has stopped this week and produces strange and inconsistent results. It continues to work on my other laptop running Windows 10. I tried removing PERSONAL.XLSB and recreating it, but the macro still doesn't work correctly. After writing a work around for one of the errors (it started returning an equals sign instead of the contents of a cell in a closed workbook) it went from 1 minute run time to about 2 hours. Meanwhile the other laptop completes the original
unmodified macro in about a minute.

I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions that I might try to get Excel working again for  my macros? I run the desktop version of Excel from Microsoft 365.

Update:
I noticed that the slow down is because after I set `Application.calculation = xlCalculationManual` it gets mysteriously reset back to `xlCalculationAutomatic` after opening a workbook:

```
                debugPrint "--2.1 else", Application.calculation = xlCalculationManual

                Set reportFileWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=templateFileFull, passWord:=pw)
                
                debugPrint "--2.2 else", Application.calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

debugPrint is my own function that just puts the debug output in to a box to make it more prominent. Why would opening the workbook cause `Application.calculation` to reset back to Automatic?

Comment: Without the code, it is hard to help.

Comment: I suspect it isn't is a code issue. IT has worked and continues to work. The main difference is the upgraded OS. Right now it works even on the upgraded laptop, but with a 2 hour run time. The macro essentially though, matches a file mask for the files to import, works out if they are relevant to the report and then copies a worksheet in each one in to the main report file. Isolating a portion of the code,  even on the same laptop wasn't helpful as it suddenly would work flawlessly - just not as whole. I can see about pasting the code in here but it is quite a few lines.

Comment: We need a [mcve].  You need to whittle the code down to what is not working.  If you throw a wall of code up, most will just pass by.  But without offending code we cannot help.  I have updated to win 11 and do not have any problems with my code, so we cannot guess as to the issue.

Comment: Okay. It is definitely much easier to paste in 300 lines than to isolate the section I think is the bottleneck. I'll see about doing that, but it will either be in a few hours or tomorrow. I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: There are at least 2 things going on, but I did discover why there is a slow down. I set `Application.calculation = xlCalculationManual` and after this line `Set reportFileWB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=templateFileFull, passWord:=pw)` it mysteriously gets set back to `xlCalculationAutomatic`. This slows things down later when I am inserting all the workbooks where there is another problem. Why would that line change  `Application.calculation` back to automatic? I put `debug.Print` before and after the line to discover this.

Comment: @Ben  You need to show some code as posting snippets in the comments doesn't help.  My guess is that you are opening a new instance of the excel app so it is retaining what is set in the options and not what you are setting but again this is just a guess as you have supplied no code to review.

Comment: I put the code snippet in my edited question above. I explicitly set Application.calculation to Manual at the start of my macro and then I put in a load of debug.Prints all the way through to track where it gets set back to Automatic. I also load Excel from scratch with nothing else in place. I do not manually set the calculation options to manual from the Excel GUI. The first debugPrint shows manual and the 2nd, right after opening the workbook, shows it as automatic.